# How to specify the thousands and decimal separator used by GWT's NumberFormat

Tags: gwt, number-formatting

In the doc of GWT's NumberFormat class (http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/NumberFormat.html) I read:

*"The prefixes, suffixes, and various symbols used for infinity, digits, **thousands separators, decimal separators**, etc. **may be set to arbitrary values**, and they will appear properly during formatting. However, care must be taken that the symbols and strings do not conflict, or parsing will be unreliable. For example, the decimal separator and thousands separator should be distinct characters, or parsing will be impossible."*

My question is, how do I make sure that "." is used as thousands separator and "," as decimal separator independently of the user's locale settings?
In other words when I use the pattern "###,###,###.######" I want GWT to format the double value 1234567.89 **always** as "1.234.567,89" no matter what the user's locale is.

Comment: Updated to my final answers. It looks like GWT is planning to support this, but has not yet done so. See my suggested hack.

Answer (score 4):

Solving this took some work. From the [docs](https://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/NumberFormat.html) and [source](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/NumberFormat.java?r=7060) for NumberFormatter, it looks like only Locales can be used to set these values. They do say you can set the **group separator** but no such examples worked for me. While you might think the Java way to do this at the bottom would work since GWT emulates the [DecimalFormat](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/changes/jat/numberformat-r2942/user/super/com/google/gwt/emul/java/text/DecimalFormat.java?spec=svn2951&r=2946) and [DecimalFormalSymbols](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/changes/jat/numberformat-r2942/user/super/com/google/gwt/emul/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.java?r=2950) classes, they do not [formally support](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation) them. Perhaps they will in the future. Further, they say in the [LocaleInfo class](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/LocaleInfo.java?r=8252) that you can modify a locale, I found no such methods allowing this.

So, here is the **Hack way to do it**:

```
    NumberFormat.getFormat("#,##0.0#").format(2342442.23d).replace(",", "@");
```

**Right way, but not yet GWT supported**:

Use the decimal formatter:

```
    // formatter
    DecimalFormat format= new DecimalFormat();
    // custom symbol
    DecimalFormatSymbols customSymbols=new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    customSymbols.setGroupingSeparator('@');
    format.setDecimalFormatSymbols(customSymbols);
    // test
    String formattedString = format.format(2342442.23d);
```

The output:

> 2@342@442.23

Comment: When trying to use DecimalFormat I get: "class 'java.text.DecimalFormat' is not present in JRE Emulation library so it cannot be used in client code".

Comment: Dang... odd since it is emulated. I'll post to the GWT devs.

Answer (score 3):

I just came across the same issue. I solved it like this:

```
public String formatAmount(Double amount) {
    String pattern = "#,##0.00";
    String groupingSeparator = LocaleInfo.getCurrentLocale().getNumberConstants().groupingSeparator();
    String decimalSeparator = LocaleInfo.getCurrentLocale().getNumberConstants().decimalSeparator();
    NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getFormat(pattern);
    return format.format(amount).replace(groupingSeparator, "'").replace(decimalSeparator, ".");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I've used is override the GWT's `LocaleInfoImpl` in this way:

1. Taking a look at LocaleInfo you can see it uses a private static instance [LocaleInfo line 36](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/blob/master/user/src/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/LocaleInfo.java#L36) that build using `GWT.create(LocaleInfoImpl.class)`
2. Using [GWT Deferred binding](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred.html) we can override the LocalInfoImpl by a custom implementation:

> ```
> <replace-with class="your.app.package.to.CustomLocaleInfoImpl">
>   <when-type-is class="com.google.gwt.i18n.client.impl.LocaleInfoImpl" />
> </replace-with>
> ```

3. Extend the LocaleInfoImpl in a similar way of this, just overriding the method `getNumberConstant`:

```
public class CustomLocaleInfoImpl extends LocaleInfoImpl {

    @Override
    public NumberConstants getNumberConstants() {
        final NumberConstants nc = super.getNumberConstants();
        return new NumberConstants() {
            @Override
            public String notANumber() {
                return nc.notANumber();
            }

            @Override
            public String currencyPattern() {
                return nc.currencyPattern();
            }

            @Override
            public String decimalPattern() {
                return nc.decimalPattern();
            }

            @Override
            public String decimalSeparator() {
                return nc.decimalSeparator();
            }

            @Override
            public String defCurrencyCode() {
                return nc.defCurrencyCode();
            }

            @Override
            public String exponentialSymbol() {
                return nc.exponentialSymbol();
            }

            @Override
            public String globalCurrencyPattern() {
                return nc.globalCurrencyPattern();
            }

            @Override
            public String groupingSeparator() {
                return "@";//or any custom separator you desire
            }

            @Override
            public String infinity() {
                return nc.infinity();
            }

            @Override
            public String minusSign() {
                return nc.minusSign();
            }

            @Override
            public String monetaryGroupingSeparator() {
                return nc.monetaryGroupingSeparator();
            }

            @Override
            public String monetarySeparator() {
                return nc.monetarySeparator();
            }

            @Override
            public String percent() {
                return nc.percent();
            }

            @Override
            public String percentPattern() {
                return nc.percentPattern();
            }

            @Override
            public String perMill() {
                return nc.perMill();
            }

            @Override
            public String plusSign() {
                return nc.plusSign();
            }

            @Override
            public String scientificPattern() {
                return nc.scientificPattern();
            }

            @Override
            public String simpleCurrencyPattern() {
                return nc.simpleCurrencyPattern();
            }

            @Override
            public String zeroDigit() {
                return nc.zeroDigit();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very nice solution, but i cannot make it work. It seems that GWT does not  execute <replace-with> rule and I do not know why. I am using GWT 2.8.1

Comment: I'm using 2.8.1 also and it worked for me, perhaps you can add some logs in order to trace the execution

Comment: I posted here all I could: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51819228/gwt-replace-with-not-working. Please comment if you have some ideas.